# Meaning of "in charges" in a sentence

Tags: meaning

> Vodafone error sees customers hit by **thousands in charges**

What is the meaning of *in charges* here?

I understand *in charge* mean to "be in control" or like this. But in this sentence how to understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Charge" (noun) can mean:

> the amount of money that you have to pay for something, especially for
>   an activity or service

[Charge (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/charge)

Vodafone is a UK mobile phone company; they made an error which resulted in customers being billed for thousands of pounds (in charges) (for services they had not received).

In "in charges", "in" can be replaced with 'of'.

Comment: for me, (in charges) was something new... 
thx

Comment: In "in charges", consider "in" to mean 'consisting of'.